# Distance between surge arrester

Tags: surge-protection

I'm installing surge arrester to protect a server room full of machines using the following page as a guide

http://engineering.electrical-equipment.org/electrical-distribution/how-choose-surge-protection-device.html

It said that it is required to put surge arrester devices between the low voltage input and the machines that want to be protected if the distance between them is more than 30 meter. My question is, what it the distance is less than 30 meter? Do I install only in the input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site says that for distances over 30 m, additional protection is suggested ("should"), not required ("shall").  For shorter distances, it depends on how expensive and delicate the equipment is, and where you are located.  Florida and Georgia have the greatest number of lightning strikes per year, so in those areas I would have individual protection for every piece of equipment no matter what the distance.